# com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException

Tags: android, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoinj

When I implement these two dependencies in my project:

- For BTC `implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'`
- For BCH `implementation 'cash.bitcoinj:bitcoincashj-examples:0.14.5.2'`

This error will occur:

> Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org.bitcoin.production.checkpoints.txt'

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

This issue appears because **bitcoincashj-examples** library also transit `org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.5.2` dependency.

All that you need to do is exclude `org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.5.2` dependency from **bitcoincashj-examples** library.

```
implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
implementation ('cash.bitcoinj:bitcoincashj-examples:0.14.5.2'){
    exclude group: 'cash.bitcoinj', module: 'bitcoinj-core'
}
```

Comment: I have try this suggestion but it gives an another error        **Program type already present: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

Comment: @Sam_S please edit your question and add full build.gradle

Comment: implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
    implementation ('cash.bitcoinj:bitcoincashj-examples:0.14.5.2'){
        exclude group: 'cash.bitcoinj', module: 'bitcoinj-core'
    }
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.2.0"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.2.0"
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.20'

Comment: this is my dependencies for using btc and bch

Comment: @Sam_S try to remove  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'  dependency from your build.gradle, because the slf4j-simple library already transit it to your project

Comment: Its not working for bch. It creates only btc wallet in both.

Comment: @Sam_S I can only suggest you give me your full build.gradle file, and I will try to give you a solution